# Is it possible to transform specific columns using Hive Streaming?

Tags: python, streaming, hive

The syntax below works:

```
SELECT TRANSFORM(col1,col2,col3) USING 'python script.py' AS col_1,col_2,col_3 FROM...
```

The python script actually only transforms col3, while col1, col2 are just passing through python script without any change. I want to re-use this python script so that I can replace col1, col2 with any arbitrary columns as long as col1 is passed through. But the two following codes don't work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, TRANSFORM(col3) USING 'python script.py' AS col_1 FROM... 

SELECT TRANSFORM(col3) USING 'python script.py' AS col_3, col1, col2 FROM...
```

If there a way to only pass a subset of selected columns to the streaming script while makes other selected columns walk away from the streaming process?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work because a transform can return more than one rows. Imagine if script.py for some col3 returns 2 rows (col31 and col32). What would the syntax mean? Return col1, col2, col31 and col1, col2, col32?

Comment: What if the script returns only one column? Can't we use it on one column only?